# init - 'does not name type' error in small survey app C++

Tags: c++

Trying to run and compile keeps getting . I've just started learning C++.

Is there something else i need to add to make this program run?

```
error: 'init' does not name a type
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

init main()
{
    int name;
    int number;
    int email;
    int success = "Your information was successfully submitted"
    std::cout << "Please enter your name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Please enter your Phone number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << "And Finally, enter your email address" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> email;
    std::cout << success << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main()` not `init main()` :-)

Comment: You are also missing a `;` at the end of line 10.

Comment: @Swordfish Not to mention that an `int` can't be properly initialized with a `const char*` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have

```
init main()
```

this should be

```
int main()
```

---

Since `main()` is a function (and since this is C++, so it requires a return type), the compiler would check if `init` is a valid type. It is not. So an error is thrown.

> `error: 'init' does not name a type`

Read more: [what should `main` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c),